# Swift Multiply Array Index

Tags: arrays, swift, function, class

here is klass1;

```
class Klass1 {

let name:[String]
let number:[Double]

init(name: [String], number: [Double]) {
     self.name = name
     self.number = number
     }
}
```

end of class

```
var data1 = [Klass1]()

let xxx = ["name1","name2","name3"]
let yyy = [1,2,3]

setupKlass1(){
data1.append(Klass1(name: xxx, number: yyy))
}
```

i want to take all data from data1(each name and number values)  and append to data2 as Klass2

here is Klass2 as below;

```
class Klass2 {

let name:String
let number:Double

init(name: String, number: Double) {
     self.name = name
     self.number = number
     }

}
end of class
var data2 = [Klass2]()
```

Comment: You have not given much information as to how you want to map names which is an array in Klass1 to a name in Klass2 which is just a String. However, you can use enumerator on data1 to iterate on each Klass1 object and if required, then on each item in name of Klass1 and keep creating Klass2 objects and also appending them to data2

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question here. That's not only a problem because stating the question explicitly is good form, or because it'd help us understand exactly what you're asking; figuring out how to state your question can give you insight into what you're really trying to do and where you're stuck.

Comment: Sorry for wrong telling ://

i want to take all data from data1(each name and number values) and append to data2 as Klass2

Comment: And you can't because you don't know ______?  What's preventing you from writing an `append()` method, for example?

Answer (score 3):

I think you would like to get something like this

```
var data2: [Klass2] = data1.flatMap {
    zip($0.name, $0.number).map {
        Klass2(name: $0, number: $1)
    }
}
```